# How to extract numbers from a mixed string in R

Tags: r

```
df
   Chromosome aaChange
1          16 p.E548fs
2          16   p.S64X
3          16   p.P23H
4          16   p.G18V
5          16  p.L251S
```

I'm trying to extract numbers from `aaChange`, namely `584`, `64`, `23`, `18`, `251`. I've run the code below:

```
    df <- tidyr::extract(df, aaChange, into = 'Protein_position', ".*(\\d+).*", 
                         remove = F, convert = T)
```

But the output is:

```
df
   Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
1          16 p.E548fs                8
2          16   p.S64X                4
3          16   p.P23H                3
4          16   p.G18V                8
5          16  p.L251S                1
```

I dont know how to modify the regex. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output? For example, 548 instead of 8 for the first row?

Comment: @Jeremy I want to extract 548 in the first row.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the number parts of `aaChange` are always going to be grouped together you can use something very simple:

```
tidyr::extract(df, aaChange, into = 'Protein_position', "(\\d+)", remove = F, convert = T)
#>   Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
#> 1         16 p.E548fs              548
#> 2         16   p.S64X               64
#> 3         16   p.P23H               23
#> 4         16   p.G18V               18
#> 5         16  p.L251S              251
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also do:

```
df = data.frame(aaChange = c("p.E548fs", "p.S64X", "p.P23H", "p.G18V", "p.L251S"))
df$Protein_position = as.numeric(gsub("\\D", "", df$aaChange))
```

```
df
 aaChange Protein_position
1 p.E548fs              548
2   p.S64X               64
3   p.P23H               23
4   p.G18V               18
5  p.L251S              251
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(string)
df %>% mutate(Protein_position = str_extract(aaChange, '(?<=p\\.[A-Z])\\d+(?=[A-z]{1,2})'))
  Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
1         16 p.E548fs              548
2         16   p.S64X               64
3         16   p.P23H               23
4         16   p.G18V               18
5         16  p.L251S              251
```

Data used:

```
df
  Chromosome aaChange
1         16 p.E548fs
2         16   p.S64X
3         16   p.P23H
4         16   p.G18V
5         16  p.L251S
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `sub` from `base R`

```
df$Protein_position <- as.numeric(sub("^\\D+(\\d+).*", "\\1", df$aaChange))
df$Protein_position
#[1] 548  64  23  18 251
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `regmatches` to extract all numbers

```
transform(
  df,
  Protein_position = as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(aaChange, gregexpr("\\d+", aaChange))))
)
```

which gives

```
  Chromosome aaChange Protein_position
1         16 p.E548fs              548
2         16   p.S64X               64
3         16   p.P23H               23
4         16   p.G18V               18
5         16  p.L251S              251
```