# How to remove specific numbers from a column

Tags: r

Say I have a string like this :

`years<-c("IMG_Sr 179 P.jpg", "IMG_Sr 18 L (2).jpg", "IMG_Sr 182 P.jpg")`

The output I expect from this is :
`c(179, 18,182)`

What can I do for this?

Comment: Try regular expression

Comment: Specifically, remove the "IMG_Sr " part at the beginning of the string and then remove everything that comes after the following number, i.e. the " P.jpg" and so on things.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [R extract first number from string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23323321/r-extract-first-number-from-string)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a mixed string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521189/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-mixed-string-in-r)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your desired output is the only part of the string that is a number surrounded by spaces then you can use:

`gsub(".* (\\d*) .*", "\\1", years)`

Comment: This worked. what if I need an output like this : ` c(179 P, 18 L,182 P)`

Comment: `gsub(".* ([[:digit:]]* [[:alpha:]]).*", "\\1", years)` gets you numbers after a space followed by space followed by a single letter. ([[:digit:]] is pretty much the same as \\d)

Comment: thank you! Can you tell me where I can learn the basics of how you specify these patterns using Regex?

Comment: I'd reccommend [regexone.com](https://regexone.com/) followed by issuing the command: `?regex` in an R session for a quick introduction to regular expressions.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
    readr::parse_number(years)
```