# How to get rid of all non-numerical characters in a dataframe?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe:

```
world <- structure(list(delete_header = c("0.000000QP table data", "0.067018QP table data", 
"0.134035QP table data", "0.201053QP table data", "0.268070QP table data", 
"0.335103QP table data")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

that looks like

```
          delete_header
1 0.000000QP table data
2 0.067018QP table data
3 0.134035QP table data
4 0.201053QP table data
5 0.268070QP table data
6 0.335103QP table data
```

Now, I want to get rid of all the characters and leave only the numerical values behind as such:

```
          delete_header
1 0.000000
2 0.067018
3 0.134035
4 0.201053
5 0.268070
6 0.335103
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to extract numbers from a mixed string in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67521189/how-to-extract-numbers-from-a-mixed-string-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `parse_number` from `readr`

```
world$delete_header <- readr::parse_number(world$delete_header)
world$delete_header
#[1] 0.000000 0.067018 0.134035 0.201053 0.268070 0.335103
```

---

Or in `base R` with `gsub`

```
as.numeric(gsub("[^0-9.]+", "", world$delete_header))
```

---

if we want to write to a .txt file

```
cat(paste(capture.output(world), collapse="\n"), 
        file = file.path(getwd(), "name.txt"))
```

-output

[image]

Comment: Hi @akrun Thank you for your response. Both of your code works well.

Comment: Do you know how I can preserve the trailing zeros when I export the dataframe to txt?

Comment: For instance, when I do export to txt `write.table(world, file = "name.txt", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names=FALSE)`, row #1 and #5 turn into 0. and 0.26707, respectively

Comment: @Drew which function you are using for exporting.  You may use `cat(world, file = "name.txt")`

Comment: Thank you. Any idea why it's giving me this error? `Error in cat(world, file = "name.txt") : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'`

Comment: Try `cat( paste(capture.output(world), collapse="\n"), file = 'name.txt')

Comment: Still not working; I'll post this is as a separate question. Thanks

Comment: @Drew I tried the same code on my system and it created with the nice format

Comment: @Drew when you say it is not working, ar eyou still getting error.  I updated with the output I am getting with an image

Comment: Oh actually, you're right. It did work in keeping the trailling zeros. I still need to get rid of the row and column names though. What's the equivalent for row.names = FALSE and col.names = FALSE for `cat()`?

Comment: @Drew just extract the vector and use `cat(paste(world$delete_header, collapse="\n"), file = file.path(getwd(), "name.txt"))`

Comment: If I do that then I lose the integrity of the row structure. I need one value per row per line as in your output image for this dataset to be cross-validated with another. My apologies for the many questions

Comment: @Drew How about converting to character column and then use write.table i.w. `world$delete_header <- sprintf('%.6f', world$delete_header)`

Comment: Ah very close. The output is now nested in quotation marks: `"0.000000"`

Comment: It is because `quote = TRUE` by default in `write.table`. change that `quote = FALSE`

Comment: Amazing. It's perfect. You're a life-saver